# Rewrite an expression without absolute value signs

Tags: linear-algebra, absolute-value

I'm trying to rewrite $2x − |x − |x + 1||$ without the absolute value signs. If I input this into Wolfram Alpha, it returns the alternate form: $2x-\sqrt{\left(x-\sqrt{(x+1)^2}\right)^2}$.
Any help on how to arrive to this form would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\;\sqrt{a^2}=|a|\;$

Comment: Of course that alternate form is only valid for real $x$.

Comment: Thanks @DonAntonio, it makes a lot of sense now